# Capture Screen with Javascript, but result looks too different. Is there a better alternative to html3canvas.js?

Tags: javascript, php, screenshot, html2canvas, screen-capture

I am using html2canvas.js to capture my screen.
But the result looks very different from the actual screen (see the image).

The Scroll-area is broken in the image.
Table-Lines are not visible.
The OpenStreetMap is just white.

This is too deiferent.

Is there a better option than html2canvas?
I guess an actual screenshot is not possible in Javascript.
So what choice do I have?
Java-applets is not possible in my case.
And the screen-capturing has to work in multiple browsers (Chrome and IE9+).
So a chrome-only-solution is not possible too.

Anyone having a great idea?

[left: html2canvas, right: original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XbHY.png)

Comment: Is there maybe a way to get the screen pixel by pixel?

Comment: "html3canvas" does not exist. The script is still in a very experimental state, so I don't recommend using it in a production environment nor start building applications with it yet, as there will be still major changes made. Read this: https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas#how-does-it-work

Comment: Okay, thank you.
I knew it was still in a "experimental" state because it was not even Version 1.0.
But everyone mentioned html2canvas when I googled a suitable JavaScript-library.

Anything you can recommend?

Comment: post your html and css and read the link that I have sent in the first comment https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas#how-does-it-work (read about "proxy")

Comment: What would the proxy change exactely?

Comment: proxy solve issues with CORs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS